# MySQL database layers invisible in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, mysql

I'm encoutering a problem when connecting a MySQL database to QGIS. When the connection is established and a layer is imported, the layer itself will not render and thus isn't visible. The layer becomes visible when i export/save it as a .shp file.

I've tried different CRS-systems, encoding systems, i've checked style properties but nothing works. When zooming to map layer the extends are located correctly, this means the coordinates are set according to the given coordinate system. It appears only the rendering of the live database objects is going wrong. Did someone encounter this issue before or knows a solution or workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

there is an active ticket on this issue:
https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13836